# How do I ask about an application for a second time without sounding pushy?

Tags: job-search, email

I was contacted on LinkedIn about a potential job. The person who contacted me was the recruitment manager at the company, not an outside recruiter. I applied for the job through the email he sent and a day later got an email from him saying he would talk to the technical director and get back to me. I waited a couple of weeks and heard nothing so I emailed back asking for an update. I got a response that day saying he would get back to me before the weekend, but I still haven't heard anything. That was over a week ago.

I understand that people are busy and I'm happy to wait for a while, but how long should I wait before emailing again, if I should at all?

If I do email again how do I do so without sounding pushy or impatient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want to email, then I'd just reply to the last message with something quick such as:

> Hi x,
>
> Sorry to bother you again, but I was just wondering if there was an update at all following on from your previous message?

However, at this point I'd be seriously considering whether to follow through on this particular application - if they're delaying you for weeks and continually promising to get back to you (but not doing so), it's not a great sign. It seems that they're either not particularly interested in filling the role, or not particularly interested in you as a candidate for whatever reason.

If it were me I'd just drop it entirely until (if) I heard back, and be using my time to seek employment elsewhere. It's not about sounding pushy, but rather about continually investing time in chasing up a company that seems to be a nightmare with communication. If it's this bad now, then imagine how much time you could waste trying to sort out interviews / contracts later on!

Answer (score 1):

> If I do email again how do I do so without sounding pushy or
>   impatient?

At this point you need to **pick up the phone and call them**.

Emails can get lost sometimes, or people just get busy and forget.  I would either call them directly or let this one go.